# Do Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs work with websockets and javascript?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am interested in using Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs.  However, my first "client" will be a websocket based connection to a ASP.NET MVC site with Knockout.  Currently, I'm trying out SignalR to push notification to the clients.

However, it looks like this would be much easier if I could use SB Notification Hubs.  All of  [the examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx) are Windows or iOS.

Can you use Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs with WebSocket based HTML clients?

Comment: There is a more updated status on this, please see my answer. I will update this as I hear more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a Program Manager in the Service Bus team.
There is no plan to support WebSockets on HTML as an output pipe for Notification Hubs.
At the moment your best bet is to use SignalR, which can be scaled out using Service Bus.

What are the characteristics of Notification Hubs that make you say that it would be preferable to SignalR?

Comment: My choices are SignalR + Service Bus, or a dedicated service like Pusher.  With SignalR, i am deploying it on my web roles in Azure.  It may not scale at the same rate as my web usage.  Having this through a dedicated service like notification hubs means that I don't have to think about the server side issues associated with hosting SignalR or it's impact on the rest of my application.

Comment: I was interested in using the Notification Hub instead of SignalR to move the load out of the server. The idea is to cut the load by half by letting Azure notify the web browser of new messages, thus removing the need for persistent connections on our server. At the age of rich clients, we're trying to cut the load on the server as much as we can

Comment: The latest [update on this (March-2016)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/4621850-add-support-for-azure-notification-hubs-to-push-me) cotradicts this answer.

Answer (score 2):

We spent several days trying to do what you describe, but we were unable to get SignalR/WebSockets to work on Azure Cloud. SignalR/WebSockets failed every time, spawning infinite loops of connection failures/reconnections. We were able to get SignalR/LongPolling (not WebSockets) to work on Azure cloud successfully. We have since learned that the VM on Azure Cloud apparently does not support WebSockets at all. Our experience indicates that you probably will not be able to use WebSocket-based HTML clients with SignalR running on Azure cloud, though you can probably get LongPolling to work OK.

Comment: This works fine for me on Azure Cloud Services.  There are quite a few articles on how to make this work.

You might want to try the example for Web Sites (not the same as VM but should at least see if you have a problem somewhere else) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2013/02/27/deploy-the-signalr-getting-started-sample-as-a-windows-azure-web-site.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no support right now. This answer may be updated in the future due to these feature requests (Marked as 'Planned' by the way).

You can also add your votes to these to get them pushed faster:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/4621850-add-support-for-azure-notification-hubs-to-push-me

and here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/32466415-web-socket-support-in-notification-hubs