# Javascript client for Azure Notification Hub

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-notificationhub

I was trying to find anything about it on the internet but without a success. Let's say i'm building a simple jQuery / Angular.js application.

I want to to use some kind of PubSub service, like pusher or faye for instance, to add a live notifications to my app. Does Windows Azure Hub Service allows me to do such thing? Can i subscribe and emit azure hub notifications using plain javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Azure has an API for pushing messages directly to *mobile applications*, but I believe you'll need a web server including a [signalR hub](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/using-signalr-with-windows-azure-web-sites) for hosting/serving a plain javascript app capable of receiving such notifications (signalR will use websockets, server-sent events or fall back to ajax depending on the clients browser).

Answer (score 0):

Azure notification hubs pushes the notifications through platform notification services like APNS, GCM etc.

Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj927170.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from the Windows Azure Program Manager

[Do Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs work with websockets and javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486176/do-azure-service-bus-notification-hubs-work-with-websockets-and-javascript)

**tl;dr**

No there isn't. You can only emit.